# How to use impl<'a> From<&'a Method> for &'a str in Rust?

Tags: rust

There's this trait implementation for an enum `Method` which is self explanatory:

```
impl<'a> From<&'a Method> for &'a str {
    fn from(v: &'a Method) -> Self {
        match v {
            Method::Describe => "DESCRIBE",
            Method::GetParameter => "GET_PARAMETER",
            Method::Options => "OPTIONS",
            Method::Pause => "PAUSE",
            Method::Play => "PLAY",
            Method::PlayNotify => "PLAY_NOTIFY",
            Method::Redirect => "REDIRECT",
            Method::Setup => "SETUP",
            Method::SetParameter => "SET_PARAMETER",
            Method::Teardown => "TEARDOWN",
            Method::Extension(ref v) => v,
        }
    }
}
```

Given `let a = Method::Describe`, how can I generate a String from it?

```
let x: String = a.into()
```

won't work because `into()` works only for `str`.

I found this to work:

```
let s: &str = request.method().into();
let x: String = s.into();
```

Can I do however do everything in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like so:

```rust
let x: String = From::<&str>::from(a.into());
let y: String = Into::<&str>::into(a).to_owned();
```

Or you can define a new `From` implementation for `String`:

```
impl<'a> From<&'a Method> for String {
    fn from(x: &'a Method) -> Self {
        let x: &str = x.into();
        x.to_owned()
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this: `let z: String = a.into()`